# Is there a better, shorter code for this?

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python and one of the sites that I'm working with has one of the problem as follows:
*Given two int values, a and b, return True if either one is 6. Or if their sum or difference is 6.*

and here's my code for it

```
def love6(a, b):
  diff = a-b
  sum = a+b
  if a==6 or b==6:
    return True
  elif sum==6 or abs(diff)==6:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

This is fine and works perfect - just wondering if this could be compressed further?

Comment: BTW, it's not a Good Idea to shadow the built-in function `sum` with a variable of that name.

Comment: right, thanks - I guess it would take time to get a grasp of all the built in functions (although _sum_ should have been obvious to me)

Comment: A decent editor with syntax highlighting can be helpful with that sort of thing: if you accidentally use the name of a built-in you get immediate feedback because it's in a special colour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since two branches of your `if` do the same thing, you can merge them into one by linking them with another `or`:

```
if a==6 or b==6 or sum==6 or abs(diff)==6:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

but this is just:

```
return (a == 6 or b == 6 or sum==6 or abs(diff)==6)
```

But since all of them are testing the same equality, you can use the `in` operator like so:

```
return 6 in (a,b,sum,abs(diff))
```

It's worth avoiding the variable name `sum`, since there's a builtin function with that name. Here, you're only using it once and the operation is quite simple, so you can drop the variables completely without any appreciable loss in clarity:

```
return 6 in (a,b,a+b,abs(a-b))
```

Comment: Was waiting for someone to use `in`. I like it. But I would not use it because it is less intuitive and probably slower because it has to build the tuple. I would stick to the second version.

Comment: @spectras I.. highly doubt the time difference here would be remotely noticeable. Even using a fully short-circuiting version like PM 2Ring's answer (my second version still calculates `sum` and `diff` ahead of time) is likely to have a time difference measured in 10s of *cycles*.

Comment: Ofc. It was more about it being more intuitive. I did `timeit` out of curiosity though. When returning False, difference is about 10%. Unfortunately I cannot count cycles with `timeit` as frequency scaling kicks in, but I completely agree it's so short it's not going to matter in any real-world program.

Comment: @lvc thanks for multiple, progressive solutions - I was sure there were better ways, you & PM 2Ring have just done that

Answer (score 6):

Why waste time pre-computing the sum & absolute difference when they may not be needed?

```
def love6(a, b): 
    return a==6 or b==6 or a+b==6 or abs(a-b)==6
```

The Python `or` operator short-circuits, so the above tests are evaluated left to right, and once a True value is found, no more tests are performed. Eg, if `a` or `b` equal 6, then the sum isn't calculated, and the absolute difference is only calculated if neither `a` nor `b` equal 6, and their sum isn't 6.

Comment: Without disputing that short circuiting is a useful thing to learn and know about, I don't think 'wasting time' is a good way to frame it here (the time difference is going to be truly negligible).

Comment: @lvc: Fair point, although it's not just the calculation time that's saved - there's also the time & RAM saved in not creating the temporary objects that hold the calculation results. Sure, it's all tiny stuff in this example. But if we were doing this in a loop over a billion pairs of `(a, b)` the performance difference would be noticeable (although the impact on RAM probably wouldn't be that bad, due to the way Python handles integer objects).

Comment: The RAM cost of two `int`s is roughly 60 bytes. This does go up if they're massive, so if the sum and difference are both of order 10^30 (one thousand billion billion billion), it's around 80 bytes. Aside from the effect of CPython's small integer cache, these are eligible for garbage collection as soon as the function returns, so the number of calls is immaterial. They will be fast locals, so the lookup in CPython is the same C array indexing (constant time pointer arithmetic) as for `a` and `b`. Any actual cost is paid *once*, when the function is compiled.

Comment: @awkward101: You should consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) either lvc's answer or mine if they have helped you.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks for notifying, did that - both the solutions are correct.